# Imagens aparecem no site mas não no FTP

Tags: wordpress

Estou com um problema muito estranho, pesquisei muito e não achei ninguém que tivesse algo parecido...

Migrei um site feito em Wordpress para um novo hosting, mas verifiquei que diversas imagens do site não foram migradas. Ao acessar o FTP do host antigo, vi que algumas imagens que aparecem normalmente no site, **NÃO APARECEM** no FTP.

Exemplo:
Imagem: https://renascerdistribuidor.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/53525n.jpg
Se eu acessar o FTP na pasta **uploads/2018/04**, esta imagem não está lá.

É possível que o Wordpress salve de alguma outra forma na qual eu desconheço, essas imagens?

Comment: Verifique se as imagens não foram convertidas e salvas em uma tabela da base de dados do wordpress..

Comment: Olá! Acredito que pode ser isso sim... mas você sabe qual o nome da tabela que ele cria normalmente? Pois acessei e não consegui localizar nada...